Picklist Item Search not working when making a selection for some users
We have a picklist field on our User Story work item which is a list of project codes to associate a work item with. It is a field with a format like ### - XXXX .
For some users, they can start typing and it will pull up the list of matching picklist values based upon what appears to be a partial 'contains' search. When I start typing, it does not do this same search, and I have to start typing from the first part of the string to be able to get any match at all which in our case means I have to get the ### part exactly correct.
We have combed through permissions to see if there is any difference between the users that have the search functionality working versus those that do not (there are multiple users in each bucket), and we cannot see anything different that would cause this. In my case I am an administrator for the project and 2 other administrators can do the contains search.
We are trying to determine if there is some permissions or setup thing related to this or if this is truly a bug.
We have reviewed permissions extensively to look for differences between functioning and non-functioning users.

The issue could be not with permissions. As long as you has the permissions to edit the work items, you should be able to search and set values in the fields.

For your case, you can try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

Check if the "New Boards Hubs" is turned on. Try to switch its state.


Try on different web browsers, such as Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, etc...

Try to update your web browsers to the latest version.




The 'New Boards Hubs' feature is what I needed! Thank you!
